# Cucumber scenario not running inside Intellij IDEA on WIndows 10

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

I am trying to launch cucumber scenario using 'play' icon along side each scenario inside .feature file.
When I do that on MacOS - no problems, it starts a specific scenario and runs it successfully.
But when I do the same on Windows 10 - no scenarios are being run. Even no errors displayed:

```
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.319s

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have found out that if I change name of scenario to english - it will actually run. So the problem is that name of my scenario is in russian and it get passed to --name parameter in Run Configuration.

But how to configure Intellij IDEA to accept such thing?

Comment: Do you have the "Cucumber for Java" plugin installed?

Comment: @Kajzer Yep, I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Windows Settings.
So if you go to Region > Administrative settings and open Change System Locale, there is a checkbox 'Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support'. Unchecking it will resolve this issue.

[This checkbox was causing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnqCI.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28654160)

Comment: @Reborn fixed it. Thanks!